# Load balancing between 2 applications

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I am deploying a 3rd party product as container in kubernets, ans as per their recommendation there should be 2 pods, 2 services, 2 ingress urls (only the license will be different). Say Deployment 1 exposes a https url and deployment 2 also exposes another https url. The functionality is same.

Now I want to have an external application load balancer to route the traffic between these 2 different urls in different deployment, how can we achieve this?

Comment: Do we speak about standalone k8s, GKE, EKS or AKS?

Comment: Am I right that you would like to be able to send your traffic to single URL (LB) and then dispatched to different urls (one per deployment) ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use an ingress controller, which routes traffic to the right service depending on conditions like the hostname matching an ingress.

There's many ways of doing this, but you might want to check out the [AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/) to start with, assuming you meant the AWS application load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ambassador for loadbalancing   and configure your endpoint for LB
https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/running/load-balancer/